# MATLAB - Intersection of arrays

Tags: matlab

I am trying to graphically find the intersections between two surfaces and the x-y plane. (Intersection of surface z1 with the x-y plane and intersection z2 with the x-y plane)

I have created arrays representing the surfaces z1 = 3+x+y and z2 = 4-2x-4y and the z3 for the x-y plane using meshgrid. Looking everywhere, the only command that seems I can use to find the intersections between arrays is the intersect(A,B) command where A and B are arrays. When I enter intersect(z1,z3) however, I get the error "A and B must be vectors, or 'rows' must be specified." When I try intersect (z1,z2,'rows'), I am returned a 0-by-21 empty matrix. What am I doing wrong here?

My code:

```
x = -10:10;
y = -10:10;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z1 = 3+X+Y;
z2 = 4-2.*X-4.*Y;
z3 = 0.*X+0.*Y;         %x-y plane
surf(X,Y,z1)
hold on
surf(X,Y,z2)
surf(X,Y,z3)
int1 = intersect(z1,z3,'rows');
int2 = intersect(z2,z3,'rows');
```

Comment: Couldn't you just find places where `z1==0` and `z2==0`? That would be the intersection with the x-y plane. Or do you mean that you want it to interpolate the values if you don't have the exact (X,Y) in your grid? (Also, what do you mean by "graphically" find the intersections? You could mathematically work out the intersection points - not hard - and draw them in on the graph?)

Comment: I could do it analytically. But I'm taking a Numerical methods course using MATLAB and I assume my instructor wants me to find the intersecting curves using MATLAB functions.

Comment: Read the help for `contour3d` or `contour` and see if one of these functions could help you to determine graphically the z==0 curve for both arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want the points where z1 = z2. To numerically find these, you have a couple options.

1) Numerical rootfinding: `fsolve` is capable of solving systems of equations. You can formulate the surfaces as functions of one vector, `[x;y]` and solve for the vector that makes the two surfaces equal. An example using the initial guess x=1, y=1 follows:

```
z1 = @(x) 3 + x(1) + x(2);
z2 = @(x) 4 - 2*x(1) - 4*x(2);
f = @(x) z1(x) - z2(x);

x0 = [1;1]
intersect = fsolve(@(x) f(x), x0);
```

2) Minimizing the error: If you are stuck with discrete data (arrays instead of functions) you can simply find the points where z1 - z2 is closest to zero. An easy starting point is to take the arrays Z1 and Z2 and find all points where the difference nears zero:

```
tol = 1e-3;
near_zero = abs(Z1 - Z2) < tol;
```

`near_zero` is going to be a logical array that is true whenever the difference between Z1 and Z2 is small relative to `tol`. You can use this to index into corresponding [meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) arrays for X and Y to find the coordinates of intersection.

Answer (score 0):

a simple way (no major function calls) to solve this is as follows:

```
x = -10:.1:10;
y = -10:.1:10;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z1 = 3+X+Y;
z2 = 4-2.*X-4.*Y;
z3 = z1 - z2;
[~,mn] = min(abs(z3));
```

the intersection is defined as `(x, y(mn))`.

This, of course is a numerical approximation (since you wanted a numerical method), subject to boundary condition which I haven't explored (you'll need to disregard values far from zero when performing the minimum function)

Note: if you're looking for an equation, consider performing a least squares approximation on the resulting data.